# I would like to know the regular expression for fulfill the following pattern:

Tags: regex

I would like to know the regular expression fulfill the following pattern:

- It will accept total 9 digits
- After two digit there will be a dash
- Not allowed all the zeroes
- It should not start with zero

E.g. `12-2322232 --> valid 01-2323232 --> Not valid 00-0000000 --> Not valid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use axios, fetch which comes out of the box with React, superagent etc. Here I'll show you how to use axios for server calls:

```
$npm i -S axios

import axios from 'axios' // import inside the component you will make the request.

//Make the call function.
userDataCallHandler = () => {
    axios({
        method:'post',
        url:'here the api url endpoint',
        data:{
            name:this.state.name,
            password:this.state.password
         },
         headers:{
             'Content-Type':'application/json'
             Authorization:'your token if you need it'
          }
    })
    .then(({data}) => {
          consolo.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios for further info about it.